# NMAP NSE script stopping after 900 seconds (15 minutes)

Tags: brute-force, nmap, nse

I am experimenting with ssh bruteforce over my home network using the `ssh-brute` nse script. I have a short list of usernames (just 12) but a long list of passwords (1M).

I can't seem to get the `ssh-brute` script to run longer than 900 seconds before it terminates and reports:

```
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
| ssh-brute:
|   Accounts: No valid accounts found
|_  Statistics: Performed 1556 guesses in 900 seconds, average tps: 1.9

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 903.62 seconds
```

I've read the docs for `ssh-brute`, and for the `brute`, `creds`, and `unpwdb` nse libraries, but I can't see any options or information that might be relevant (though I might have missed something). I have also searched `man nmap`, the online docs and googled for information as to why it might be terminating after 900 seconds/15 minutes, but the closest I could find is the description of the `-T5` timing template, which times out an individual host after 15 minutes without reporting any results for that host, which didn't seem to match my problem. Nonetheless, I tried to manually set `--host-timeout 48h`, but that doesn't change the behaviour.

Any clues as to what's causing this, and how to get the script to run longer than 900 seconds?

Comment: Have you tried `--script-timeout 48h` also?  https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for ssh-brute.nse](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/ssh-brute.html) mentions:

`unpwdb.timelimit`

https://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/unpwdb.html#script-args

> **unpwdb.timelimit**
>
> The maximum amount of time that any iterator will run
> before stopping. The value is in seconds by default and you can follow
> it with ms, s, m, or h for milliseconds, seconds, minutes, or hours.
> For example, unpwdb.timelimit=30m or unpwdb.timelimit=.5h for 30
> minutes. The default depends on the timing template level (see the
> module description). Use the value 0 to disable the time limit.

Comment: `unpwdb.timelimit` seems to be it, I could have saved myself a lot of time by noticing that myself! Tested with `unpwdb.timelimit=1m` and it ran for 1 minute and showed results exactly as above. Thank you.